# Check Reasoning On Calculation Involving Diagonal Matrix and Matrix and Hadamard Products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hadamard-product

I apologize in advance, as I kind of realize this is a dumb question.  But I need a little more mathematical rigor to my naive logic.

Suppose I have an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix, $\mathbf{A}$, and 2 vectors $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ of length $n$.  Now I want to show more generally that,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{v}^{\text{-}1} \circ \mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{w} \circ \mathbf{v}\right) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{w}
\end{align*}
$$
where $\circ$ denotes the hadamard product (element-wise) and $\mathbf{v}^{\text{-}1} = \left(\dfrac{1}{\mathbf{v}}\right)$.  Not sure if it matters, but all the diagonal elements of $\mathbf{A}$ lie in the interval $[0, 1]$.

Since $A$ is a diagonal matrix then,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{A} (\mathbf{w} \circ \mathbf{v}) = (\mathbf{w} \circ \mathbf{v}) \mathbf{A}
\end{align*}
$$
which means,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{v}^{\text{-}1} \circ \mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{w} \circ \mathbf{v}\right) = \mathbf{v}^{\text{-}1}\circ \left(\mathbf{w} \circ \mathbf{v}\right)\mathbf{A}
\end{align*}
$$
Now it's easy to see my proposition,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{v}^{\text{-}1}\circ \left(\mathbf{w} \circ \mathbf{v}\right)\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{w}\mathbf{A}
\end{align*}
$$
because,
$$
\mathbf{v}^{\text{-}1}\circ \left(\mathbf{w} \circ \mathbf{v}\right) = \dfrac{ \left(\mathbf{w} \circ \mathbf{v}\right)}{\mathbf{v}} = \mathbf{w}
$$
Does this reasoning make sense?

And because $\mathbf{A}$ is diagonal, $\mathbf{w}\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{w}$.

Comment: there is no coupling of matrix elements, so your identity is just $n$ uncoupled scalar identities, each of which is trivial true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\,\,A = {\rm Diag}(a)$

Then there is a simple rule for switching between matrix and Hadamard multiplication
$$Ax=a\circ x$$
Apply this rule (and the commutivity of Hadamard products) to the current problem
$$\eqalign{
v^{-1}\circ A(w\circ v)
  &= v^{-1}\circ a\circ(w\circ v) \cr
  &= v^{-1}\circ v\circ a\circ w \cr
  &= a\circ w \cr
  &= Aw \cr
}$$